# Map and Filter, Haskell

Tags: haskell

Hi I was wondering how to use the `map` and `filter` function in haskell to get the amount of a number in the list, That was confusing sorry here's an example.

```
let a = [[1,2,1,2,1,1,1],[1,2],[3,4],[3,2]]
```

And I want use `map` to find out how many `1s` are in each sub-list so the outcome would be

```
[5,1,0,0]
```

Any idea how to do it, I'm guessing its easy and im just missing something, cheers, my approach is

```
let ones = map(\x length (filter (\z -> z == 1)x) )a
```

but this is getting errors

Comment: You should post your approach.

Comment: This is almost correct, you are just lacking the -> after \x

Comment: You have syntax errors in your code. The first lambda expression is missing a `->`.

Answer (score 3):

First get the filter function:

```
 ((==) 1)
```

This will filter all other elements than 1 from a list:

```
 filter ((==) 1)
```

Then combine it with the length function through function composition:

```
 (length . filter ((==) 1))
```

Finally, map the array of lists with that function and you're done!

```
 map (length . filter ((==) 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Break the problem into small steps.

Step 1. Count the number of 1s in a list. Make a function `count1s :: [Int] -> Int` using `length` and `filter`.

Step 2. Use `map` to apply `count1s` to each list in the outer list.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
let ones = map(\x length (filter (\z -> z == 1)x) )a
```

Very good attempt, and almost correct! Let's paste it into GHCi, it spouts back:

```
<interactive>:9:35: Parse error in pattern: \ z -> z == 1
```

So what does this mean? This means that it thinks it's looking at a *pattern* and that it's failed to *read* it (parsing its text). If we just look at that thing, it's not a pattern! Why does it think it's looking at a pattern?

Because of the earlier `\x` which was not followed by a `->`. In the arguments of a function literal, you're allowed to pattern-match! You can write `\(y:_) x -> y + x` and that will be the same as `(+) . head`, taking the head of one list and adding it to the second number provided.

Inserting it we get:

```
let ones = map(\x -> length (filter (\z -> z == 1)x) )a
```

Which gives a further error:

```
<interactive>:10:55: Not in scope: ‘a’
```

This is because I forgot to explicitly define `a`, so it's easy to fix:

```
let ones a = map(\x -> length (filter (\z -> z == 1)x) )a
```

Compiles, and then:

```
Prelude> ones [[1,2,1,2,1,1,1],[1,2],[3,4],[3,2]]
[5,1,0,0]
```

as desired. But we're not done yet, let's simplify!

First off there is `\z -> z == 1` which is easier written using [operator sections](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator) as `(1 ==)`. I would recommend always putting in that space so that it looks a little extra "incomplete".

Then `\x -> length (filter (1 ==) x)` is a little wordy too, we can instead use the [function composition operator](https://wiki.haskell.org/Function_composition) `.` to write this as `length . filter (1 ==)`. If you get confused about *precedence* here, remember that parentheses always happen first, then functions, then operators... so this is `(.) length (filter (1 ==))` if you really wrote it out.

Once you have that, give it a name and a type signature in a source file!

```
countOnes :: (Eq a, Num a) => [a] -> Int
countOnes = length . filter (1 ==)
```

Then I would write `map countOnes` wherever you're actually using this code.